# What is a good blogging site for C#.NET

Tags: .net, web, blogs

I wish to blog about unit test naming conventions in .NET, and may wish to blog more about C#.NET or more general development topics in the future.

I know there are several popular blogging sites, and for the most part it's up to personal preference, but what are the best designed or most popular blogging sites someone might begin in?

Comment: Do you plan to use live examples or just blog about C#?

Comment: They will definitely include live examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have the [copy code as html](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf) VS plug-in or something similar, I don't think it really matters. So [blogger.com](http://blogger.com) for example.

Comment: It looks like the plugin only supports VS 2008, and I don't have that.